# Custom session handler in php using db

Tags: php, session

I am having problem with implementing custom session handler in php.
The code:
http://pastebin.com/9QV9f22Q

I initialize this once in my frameworks bootstrap, after I have connection with db:

```
require_once 'DbSession.php';
$session = new DbSession();
session_start();
```

But then I can't view my page. Firefox gets 302 Status with "Server not found" error. Firebug says that content is 5k long, but I can't view the page.

Log after one reload:
http://pastebin.com/JYe14nGR

I wonder why it still "loses" that created DbSession instance. Do yo have any ideas? TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is based on a false premise: that you can return a *different* object from a PHP constructor.  Quite the opposite: PHP *entirely ignores* the return value from a constructor.

Here's what's actually happening.

When your code calls:

```
$session = new DbSession();
```

the `$firstTime == false` check runs, meaning `getInstance()` gets called.

`getInstance` finds no existing instance, so it calls `setup()`.

`setup()` calls `new DbSession()` again, this time passing in the argument preventing another call to `getInstance()`.  It creates the object, registers it as the session handler, and returns it.

`getInstance` shoves the object in a static variable, and then returns it to the original constructor call.  The original constructor call then drops the existing object on the ground and returns a brand new copy of itself.

You can fix *some* of this insanity by never instantiating the object outside of `setup`/`getInstance()`.  Try making the constructor protected and only ever calling `getInstance()`.

However, none of this explains why the code is malfunctioning for you.  In fact, we can't explain it either.  We're missing *all the rest of the code*, including what database adapter you're using, what ORM you're using (or even if you *are* using an ORM, your class and method names suggest it), what framework(s) might be involved, etc.

Try cutting *all* of the actual database touching from the class.  Just write files on disk.  Get *that* working first, then introduce the database layer.  Chances are that your error will become obvious at that point.